# ggtern facet wrap z axis labels do not appear

Tags: r, formatting, ggtern

I am using ggtern_1.0.6.1 and have incurred a problem.

When using facet_wrap the z axis labels on the ternary diagrams to not appear. But they appear when using facet_grid.

```
    a<-data.frame(x=c(1,1,1),y=c(1,1,1),z=c(1,1,1),b=c("a","b","c"))
    View(a)
    ggtern(a,aes(x,y,z))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~b)+theme(panel.margin.tern =unit(2, "cm")) # Z axis labels don't appear
   ggtern(a,aes(x,y,z))+geom_point()+facet_grid(.~b)+theme(panel.margin.tern =unit(2, "cm")) # Z axis labels appear
```

For formatting reasons I would rather use the facet_wrap option to plot my ternary diagrams. 
Can someone suggest how I can wrap the ternary diagrams and still obtain the z axis labels?

Answer (score 0):

`ggtern 2.0.1`, which was published on CRAN a couple of days ago after completely re-writing the package to be compatible with `ggplot2 2.0.0`. A summary of the new functionality in `ggtern 2.0.X` can be found [here](http://ahref.io/UuED1):

Your problem should be resolved with the new version, the plot placement and arrangement routine has been completely re-written, the `panel.margin.tern` theme element no-longer exists, the new version now works perfectly with `grid.arrange(...)`

```
a<-data.frame(x=c(1,1,1),y=c(1,1,1),z=c(1,1,1),b=c("a","b","c"))
A = ggtern(a,aes(x,y,z)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(~b)

B = ggtern(a,aes(x,y,z)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_grid(.~b)

grid.arrange(A + ggtitle("Facet Wrap"),
             B + ggtitle("Facet Grid"),
             nrow=2)
```

[image: solution]